# Find all real values of $k$ for which the given integral converges.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In the following, $R_k$ is the region $1 \leq x \leq \infty$, $0 \leq y \leq x^k$. 
$b$ is just a given real number.
Find all real values of $k$ for which the given integral converges: \begin{align*} \iint_{R_k} \frac{dA}{y^b}. \end{align*}

**Attempt at a solution:** We have \begin{align*} \int_{1}^{\infty} dx \int_{0}^{x^k} \frac{dy}{y^b} &= \int_{1}^{\infty} dx \Big[ \frac{y^{1-b}}{1-b} \Big]_{0}^{x^k} \\ &= \int_{1}^{\infty} dx \Big(\frac{x^{k(1-b)}}{1-b} \Big).
\end{align*}

Don't know where to go from there. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = k(1 - b)$. If $a = -1$, then $\int_1^\infty x^a\, dx$ diverges as $$\int_1^\infty x^{-1}\, dx = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_1^T x^{-1}\, dx = \lim_{T\to \infty} \ln T = \infty.$$ Suppose $a \neq -1$. Since

$$\int_1^T x^a\, dx = \frac{T^{1 + a}}{1 + a} - \frac{1}{1 + a}$$

for all $T > 1$, it follows that $\int_1^\infty x^a\, dx$ diverges if $a > -1$ and converges if $a < -1$.